# Is it possible to use Cloudera-Quickstart VM using Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, cloudera, vagrantfile, cloudera-quickstart-vm

Is it possible to use the Cloudera Quickstart VM using Vagrant? If possible then how to configure the Vagrantfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that in your system you have installed vagrant and VirtualBox from Oracle.

You can either install a vagrant "box" that contains a cloudera quickstart vm or install a, for example, an ubuntu 14.04 vagrant box, and later install the standalone CDH.

**Option 1: (recommended)** install a ubuntu 14.04 vagrant box, log in the box, install java, and then install CDH:

1) Install vagrant ubuntu 14.04:

```
> vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
> vagrant up
```

2) Log in the machine vagrant ssh
Install Oracle JAVA. I did it in this way:

```
>sudo apt-get update
>sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
>sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
>sudo apt-get update
>sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

3) Install CDH. Follow the instructions step by step as here:
http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_qs_yarn_pseudo.html

**Option 2:** You need to install a vagrant "box" that contains a cloudera quickstart vm inside.

Usually, nice experts would already create one for you. Go to

https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search

and search for "cloudera quickstart". Right now I obtain:
https://atlas.hashicorp.com/quickstart/boxes/cdh

Then, in the machine where you have installed vagrant and virtual box, simply run the command:

> vagrant init quickstart/cdh;
>   vagrant up --provider virtualbox

here "quickstart/cdh" is the name of the box, and can change, depends on your search box results.

Comment: It worked, but in my system I was having a lot of IP port conflicts.